# What does asterisk after relation name on ERD diagram mean

Tags: sql-server, erd

I created ERD diagram in my SQL Server database. One of relations have '*' sign after its name:
[image: Relation with asterisk after its name]

What does this asterisk mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that changes are pending. You made a change to the table in the diagram but did not yet save the diagram (what would probably issue an ALTER TABLE statement).